# Do characters announce genjutsu before casting, like regular jutsu and taijutsu?

Tags: naruto

In *Naruto*, they usually announce their jutsu's (i.e. fire style, fireball jutsu), but do they do the same for genjutsu?

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to Sharingan, only once it was announced, before even the jutsu was used. It was by Itachi when he was fighting Sasuke. But When Sasuke was fighting Danzo, he used  Tsukyomi on Danzo, but Sasuke didn't announce it before using the genjutsu.

When it comes to Byakugan, Neji and Hinata announce jutsus before using it.

As with Rinnegan, Nagato didn't announce when he used Gedo Rinne Tensei no justsu to revive the people of Konoha. That might be due to already he was exhausted and on the verge of death. But during the Fourth Ninja War, Madara announced before he used the Gedo Rinne Tensei no justsu.

Answer (score 1):

The only ones that come to mind is the Mangekyou Sharingan. Other than that, I don't recall them ever revealing their Genjutsu. I feel that Genjutsu is much more subtle than Ninjutsu or Taijutsu.